# YouTube app on Android "signing in" forever

Tags: nexus-4, youtube, google-apps

I use my Nexus 4 with a Google Apps account outside USA. There's no YouTube option in my GApps dashboard, as confirmed by this support page:

> YouTube is not an available service for Google Apps in countries where YouTube has not yet launched. If you're a domain administrator in one of these countries, **you will not see the option to enable YouTube as a service with Google Apps** for your domain in your Google Apps Control Panel. 
>   http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1074205

I can visit YouTube in the web browser and that works fine, although I can't sign in. (I might be able to sign in with a dummy Gmail address but that would defeat having a Google Apps account.)

When I launch YouTube app on my Nexus 4, it promptly shows a banner "signing in..." but for the reason I just mentioned, this never finishes.

**Does this mean I will never be able to use the YouTube app?! Does this really cause me to be completely locked out of YouTube on Android?** That can't be right!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a **VPN Client** to mask your original IP and circumvent lockout from youtube.

VPN clients I personally use are:

1. [HotSpot Shield](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hotspotshield.android.vpn&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImhvdHNwb3RzaGllbGQuYW5kcm9pZC52cG4iXQ..)
2. [Droid VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aed.droidvpn&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hZWQuZHJvaWR2cG4iXQ..)
3. [One Click VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vpnoneclick.android&feature=search_result)

All of it are Free but with some downsides. *Hotspot shield* gives you a US IP but will put small ads when you are browsing. *DROIDVPN* free version is limited to 100MB a day and requires to registration. *One click VPN* free has no ads and no limit, but you cannot choose your preferred country IP, it will be randomly chosen.